# How to do compositions of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

I've been given a problem that says to find $[f \circ g](x)$ and $[g\circ f](x)$. First off, what is the difference between the two? Second, how might I do this?

Comment: This sort of trivial thing can easily be googled. You have not shown any effort.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I simply don't know what the difference is. I did Google, but I found nothing useful. I turned to Stack Exchange as I've always had a good experience here and thought I might find some useful guidance. Unfortunately, that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot symbol means [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). first apply the right most function, and then apply the left function on the result.

Example:
$$f(x)=x^2$$
$$g(x)=2x$$

Then

$$(f\circ g) (x)= f(g(x))=f(2x)=(2x)^2=4x^2$$
$$(g\circ f) (x)= g(f(x))=g(x^2)=2x^2$$

Comment: Ha, I looked at your example, and it almost looked like my example.  Same $f$.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between $(f\circ g)(x)$ and $(g\circ f)(x)$ is simply the order in which the functions are.

For example, if $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=2^x$, then $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))=f(2^x)=(2^x)^2=2^{2x}$

On the contrary, $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))=g(x^2)=2^{x^2}$

More simply, $f\circ g=f(g)$ and $g\circ f=g(f)$